# ps forrest for session id

Tags: bash, shell, process

Often I want to get a nice readout what process are running and their relationship; I usually by habit runs `ps auxfww` and eventual grep for the process in question.

Having been thinking about the problem I tried to create an oneliner to get the process tree in `ps ufww` format for all processes which has the session id specified by arbitrary process name(s); ending up in following code:

```
ps ufww --sid=$(ps -C apache2 -o sess --no-headers | sort | uniq | grep -v -E '^ +0$' | awk 'NR==1{x=$0;next}NF{x=x","$0};END{gsub(/[[:space:]]*/,"",x);print x}')
```

giving for example following output:

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root      4157  0.0  0.1  41264  3120 ?        Ss   Jun11   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  4329  0.0  0.0  41264  1976 ?        S    Jun11   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  4330  0.0  0.0  41264  2028 ?        S    Jun11   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  4331  0.0  0.0  41264  2028 ?        S    Jun11   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  4332  0.0  0.0  41264  2028 ?        S    Jun11   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  4333  0.0  0.0  41264  2032 ?        S    Jun11   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  6648  0.0  0.0  41264  1884 ?        S    Jun11   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  6654  0.0  0.0  41264  1884 ?        S    Jun11   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  6655  0.0  0.0  41264  1884 ?        S    Jun11   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
```

I do wonder now if anyone has an better idea to solve this issue? Are there anything out there that is easier to "oneline" and gives above or better information? For example I would actually want to have included all childs relative any parent.

(uncertain if this should be on SF instead, but felt it was more like an programming question)

Comment: ps is an absolute monstrosity for parsing by script or by humans. I'm kinda impressed you got as far as you did. If pressed to take this farther, I'd give up on ps and work from `/proc/[0-9]*/stat` which is far more regular in its syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a slightly shorter and possibly slightly faster version of yours. It probably relies on some GNU-specific features:

```
ps ufww --sid=$(ps -C apache2 -o sess= | sort -u | grep -v -E '^ +0$' | tr $'\n' ',' | sed 's/,$/\n/; s/ //g')
```

Over 50 characters shorter.

Shorter yet and with no convoluted machinations:

```
ps -C apache2 fww -o user,pid,%cpu,%mem,vsz,rss,tty,stat,start,time,cmd
```

Look! No scrollbar!

I don't understand what you mean by:

> For example I would actually want to have included all childs relative any parent.

Isn't that what `ps auxfww` does?

If you want to easily specify a process name as a parameter, you could create a ps "family" function:

```
psf () { ps -C $1 fww -o user,pid,%cpu,%mem,vsz,rss,tty,stat,start,time,cmd; }
```

Answer (score 0):

An option to have a simple readout of processes and their relations is:

```
ps -ejH
```